# PySide2 works not efficient

Tags: python-3.x, pyside2

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow,QDialog,QLineEdit,QPushButton
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
import sys
from ui618 import Ui_MainWindow
from numpad import Ui_Dialog

class MyWindow:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.lastSelectedEditLine = None

        # main ui
        self.MainWindow = QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.MainWindow)

        # numpad
        self.QDialog = QDialog(self.MainWindow)
        self.numpad = Ui_Dialog()
        self.numpad.setupUi(self.QDialog)
        self.QDialog.setWindowFlags(Qt.Popup)

        # bind editline with numpad
        self.lineEdits = self.MainWindow.findChildren(QLineEdit)
        for item in self.lineEdits: 
            item.focusInEvent = lambda e,item=item:self.test(e,item)
    
    def save_quit(self):
        sys.exit()
            
    def bindbtn(self):
        self.ui.quit.clicked.connect(self.save_quit)

    def numpad_btn(self,a,item):
        if item.text() != '←':
            self.lastSelectedEditLine.setText(self.lastSelectedEditLine.text()+item.text())
        else:
            self.lastSelectedEditLine.setText(self.lastSelectedEditLine.text()[:-1])
    def bindNumpad(self):
        numpad_btns = self.QDialog.findChildren(QPushButton)
        for item in numpad_btns:
            item.clicked.connect(lambda ignore='ignore',item=item : self.numpad_btn(ignore,item))

    def test(self,e,item):
        self.lastSelectedEditLine = item
        this = item
        x = self.MainWindow.x()
        y = self.MainWindow.y() + self.ui.selectX.rect().bottom()
        while this.parentWidget().objectName() != 'MainWindow':
            x += this.x()
            y += this.y()
            this = this.parentWidget()

        self.QDialog.move(x, y)
        self.QDialog.show()
        item.clearFocus()
    
    def show(self):
        self.MainWindow.show()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = MyWindow()
    myWindow.show()
    myWindow.bindbtn()
    myWindow.bindNumpad()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code works as expected, the numpad shows while focusing in a qlineedit. and can write and delete to target input line.

I am new to pyside2. Is there a better way to implement the numpad? I this way, the cursor is disable, I have to edit at the end of each editline.

It take several seconds while starting, Some one know how to improve it?

[image]

Comment: what is this question asking? ... `But it seems the code is not smart?`

Comment: First of all, please ask only one question per post, and be clear with it: the title of this post refers to some "inefficiency", but it's unclear to what you're referring to. Then, it can be the case that at the *first* run it takes a variable amount of time to load: Qt is a big toolkit, but not *that* big, and if you run it the second time it should load almost instantly due to OS library caching; that said, even on pretty old systems it shouldn't take "several seconds", maybe you've some HD fragmentation issues or other background programs that slow it down (some slow and dumb antivirus?).